# Como faço pra colocar pra funcionar essa questão na linguagem Lua?

Tags: lua

```
function potencia (x,y)

  if y==0 then

    return 1

  else

    return (x*potencia(x,y-1))

 end

 algoritmoPerf = io.write("probabilidade de que cada algoritmo apresente perfeito funcionamento: ")

naoperf = 1 - algoritmoPerf

x = io.write("Digite o valor da variável aleatória: ")

resultado = 0

  for i=0,x do

    if(i<x)then

  end

 end

    pot = potencia(naoperf,i)

    resultado = pot*algoritmoPerf+resultado

print("\nO resultado da questão é ",resultado)

end
```